# Cannot visit ebay.com with safari on MacOS Sierra

Tags: safari, macos

This is how I see][image: [] ebay on Safari (MacOS Sierra)...

I have disabled all extensions I have, restarted safari, but the problem persists.

The site appears well on other browsers. Any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I would try is Safari -> Clear History. If that doesn't work, try Preferences -> Privacy -> Manage Website Data and remove any Ebay data.